# Number of entries in virtual Table

Tags: c++

In case of single inheritance hierarchy Is it always true that number of entries in a vTable is equal to number of virtual functions defined by a class?

```
class A
{
public:
  virtual void funcA(){}      
};

class B: public A
{
 public:
  virtual void funcA(){}
  virtual void funcB(){}
};
```

In the above example  vTable for classB will have only one entry for funcA()?

For multiple inheritance
Consider the below inheritance hierarchy.

```
class Base1
{ 
  public: 
   Base1(){}   
   virtual ~Base1(){}
   virtual void speakClearly(){} 
   virtual Base1 *clone() const{return new Base1;} 
  protected: 
   float data_Base1;
}; 

class Base2
{ 
  public: 
   Base2(){}
   virtual ~Base2(){}
   virtual void mumble(){} 
   virtual Base2 *clone() const{return new Base2;} 
 protected: 
   float data_Base2; 
}; 

class Derived : public Base1, public Base2
{ 
  public: 
   Derived(){}
   virtual ~Derived(){}
   virtual Derived *clone() const{return new Derived;} 
 protected: 
   float data_Derived; 
};
```

The above example is taken from book Inside C++ object model. In the book it is mentioned that Derived class will contain two vTables one for Base1 subobject and one for Base2 subobject.

The Base1 subobject vTable in the book is shown to have an entry Base2::mumble() which does not seem to be correct.
It should not have Base2::mumble() entry , Am I right?

Comment: Which version of which compiler?

Comment: @immibis: visual studio 2010

Answer (score 1):

How virtual dispatch is implemented is not specified in the Standard, so each compiler's free to do whatever it likes, provided it works.  So, there is no authoritative answer to your question.

> In the above example vTable for classB will have only one entry for funcA()?

Not necessarily, e.g. the compiler might notice that both base and derived methods are the same implementation, and create a vtable for B that has pointers to both virtual functions, then use the same vtable for A.  But, most probably wouldn't for reasons related to having an extra distinct pointer to RTTI information as discussed below....

> The Base1 subobject vTable in the book is shown to have an entry Base2::mumble() which does not seem to be correct. It should not have Base2::mumble() entry , Am I right?

From your own description, it does sound like you're right.

> number of entries in a vTable is equal to number of virtual functions defined by a class

Again, nothing's standardised, but another consideration is that there tends to need to be some non virtual-dispatch/function-adddress Runtime Type Information to support `dynamic_cast` and typeid/typeinfo, and some implementations may keep a pointer to that in the same table; whether it's considered part of the "v"table specifically is an arbitrary terminological distinction.

Comment: The below statements will not compile irrespective of the compiler you choose:   classA * a = new ClassB();

Comment: @anonymous: true... `classA * a = new ClassB();` won't compile in the context of the code in your questoin because that code doesn't have a `classA` or `ClassB`.  Did you mean `A* a = new B;`?

Comment: Sorry my bad I don't know how to enter return in the comment:    A* a = new B;    a->funcB();

Comment: also Base1* b = new Derived;    b->mumble(); this will also not compile

Comment: @anonymous: Correct: `Base1` doesn't have a `mumble` nor `A` a `funcB`, so those won't compile.  (No newlines in comments) (Also, wrap code names in backticks: ` ) (And address comments with @Name)

Comment: @anonymous: they're not meant to compile... when you assign to a base class pointer, you're retaining access to the interface (set of functions) that the base class specifies, though you can call the function implementations from the derived class if the functions are `virtual`. (It's also possible to use `dynamic_cast` to recover access to the runtime/derived type, but that's best avoided most of the time).  Maybe you should read more about OO/polymorphism at the everyday programmer level before you worry about how implementations lay out the vtable memory.